# Read multiple properties file in FTL

Tags: java, properties, freemarker

I have to create a java project library with ftl having below structure

```
src/main/resource
    +- alpha/
        +- role.ftl
        +- common.properties
    +- beta/
        +- role.ftl
        +- common.properties
```

common.properties file (alpha package)

```
org.role=admin
role.department=devops
```

common.propertes file (beta package)

```
org.role=developer
role.department=application
```

Now based on requirement, wanted to use the respective properties file in respective role.ftl file (alpha/beta folder) like below

```
<p>${org.role} is working in ${role.department}</p>
```

I am new to FTL not sure how to implement it? is basic import file statement in FTL will work for the properties file?

Answer (score 1):

Freemarker doesn't support directly importing property files.

The easiest way to get what you need is to add your property files in the freemarker model:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("common");
root.put("props", bundle);
```

And then fetch the properties as this:

```
<p>${props["org.role"]} is working in ${props["role.department"]}</p>
```